# Piping email sent to AWS SES address to PHP script on EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

We have a domain set up on Amazon SES. I need to pipe incoming emails to a specific address to a PHP script on an EC2 instance for processing. I've done this on shared servers in Cpanel using a forwarder to `|/opt/alt/php56/usr/bin/php -q /home/somesite/public_html/folder/somescript.php` but I'm not sure how to set up something similar (if possible) on SES, and Google has not been my friend in my attempts to find a solution. So my specific question is: how do I set up this sort of forwarder in SES to pipe incoming emails to a PHP script on EC2?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SES has been setup to receive the emails correctly, I think you want something like the following:

1. Start a tiny ec2 instance, install php and apache, put your php script in the public html directory (usually `/var/www/html`). The goal is to make your php script accessible to other AWS services directly.
2. Now setup an [SES "Receipt Rule"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-concepts.html) to cause a [SNS "Action"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html) that forwards the entire email body to a specific url, in this case the url to your php script.

Now all emails are received by SES will triggers the SNS action which calls your php script with the email body as a parameter to your script, and it's available to process.

But you'll want to ensure that you don't allow access to your ec2 instance to the outside world, so modify the security group to only allow http requests from inside the same subnet (plus external ssh connections so you can manage the box).

An enhancement to the above would be to host your php script which processes email contents as a function directly inside AWS Lambda instead of needing to pay to run an ec2 instance that is sitting there doing nothing most of the time.

Php is a Lambda-supported language.

I'd recommend doing it the way I suggested at first, and then trying to migrate the php script into Lambda to save money (Lambda is pretty much free for most workloads until things get absurd)

Comment: Excellent -- thanks for this, Ryan. I'll give it a shot. I'm not particularly concerned about the EC2 instance running full-time -- this is going to get daily (if not hourly) action, and the cost is ridiculously cheap. :) I looked at Lambda but it didn't appear that PHP was an accepted language without working some additional modifications.

Comment: My PHP script cannot be accessed online or via http method, how do I pipe it? I have a CLI command to pipe it out. Also PHP is no longer supported in Lambda